# Why doesn't Box<dyn std::error::Error> capture std::string::FromUtf8Error

Tags: rust

I have a trivial program below that is trying to print a `String` created from a hard coded `Vec` via `String::from_utf8`.

I am also using type aliases here to reduce verbosity (e.g. `Result<String, SomeError>` vs `Result<String>`)

```
use std::error;
use std::result;

pub type Error = Box<dyn error::Error>;
pub type Result<T> = result::Result<T, Error>;

fn main() {
    let vec = vec![65; 3];
    let text = String::from_utf8(vec).unwrap();
    println!("result {}", text);
}

fn foo() -> Result<String> {
    let vec = vec![65; 3];
    String::from_utf8(vec)
}
```

However the program doesn't compile and I get this error:

```
   |
26 | fn foo() -> Result<String> {
   |             -------------- expected `std::result::Result<String, Box<(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)>>` because of return type
27 |     let vec = vec![65; 3];
28 |     String::from_utf8(vec)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Box`, found struct `FromUtf8Error`
   |
   = note: expected enum `std::result::Result<_, Box<(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)>>`
              found enum `std::result::Result<_, FromUtf8Error>`
```

I was wondering if anyone has any insight on why this doesn't work. I would've expected `Box<dyn error::Error>` to capture all errors, but it looks like `FromUtf8Error` is an exception (or perhaps I'm just misunderstanding something). Is there a way to adjust the custom `Result` alias to generically capture `FromUtf8Error`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In one case you have `FromUtf8Error`, in the other case you have `Box<Stuff>`. `Stuff` is completely irrelevant, Rust never casts or boxes anything implicitly.
If you want to convert errors, use the `?` operator. This operator tries to convert the error type, and can do error boxing:

```rust
fn foo() -> Result<String> {
    let vec = vec![65; 3];
    Ok(String::from_utf8(vec)?)
}
```

Comment: Ahhh I see the issue now, I wasn't returning a `Result` type. Thank you!

Comment: @utpamas you _were_ returning a `Result` type, just not the right one. Another solution would be to map the error explicitly: `String::from_utf8(vec).map_err (Into::into)` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=65e77600455e15861a5688e5898e8481))